# How do I query my xml into table rows?

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2005, xquery

```
SET ARITHABORT ON;
DECLARE @xml XML;

SET @xml = CAST('<ArrayOfServicePopulation><ServicePopulation><PopulationId>1</PopulationId><PopulationName>Administrators</PopulationName><IsOther>false</IsOther></ServicePopulation><ServicePopulation><PopulationId>2</PopulationId><PopulationName>Adults</PopulationName><IsOther>false</IsOther></ServicePopulation><ServicePopulation><PopulationId>3</PopulationId><PopulationName>Business and Industry</PopulationName><IsOther>false</IsOther></ServicePopulation><ServicePopulation><PopulationId>4</PopulationId><PopulationName>Children of Substance Abusers*</PopulationName><IsOther>false</IsOther></ServicePopulation><ServicePopulation><PopulationId>5</PopulationId><PopulationName>Civic Groups/Coalitions</PopulationName><IsOther>false</IsOther></ServicePopulation></ArrayOfServicePopulation>' AS XML);

SELECT  servicePopulations.value('.', 'varchar(max)') AS [populations]
FROM    @xml.nodes('/ArrayOfServicePopulation/ServicePopulation') results ( servicePopulations )
```

When I try the above, I get everything into rows, but not separate columns. All of the data is mushed into one column as seen below:

[image]

I'm not real familiar with xquery and can't seem to find an example of how to do it. Any help would be appreciated. I feel like I'm close...but I kinda feel like I'm far away too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML;

SET @xml = '<ArrayOfServicePopulation>
               <ServicePopulation>
                  <PopulationId>1</PopulationId>
                  <PopulationName>Administrators</PopulationName>
                  <IsOther>false</IsOther>
               </ServicePopulation>
               <ServicePopulation>
                  <PopulationId>2</PopulationId>
                  <PopulationName>Adults</PopulationName>
                  <IsOther>false</IsOther>
               </ServicePopulation><ServicePopulation><PopulationId>3</PopulationId><PopulationName>Business and Industry</PopulationName><IsOther>false</IsOther></ServicePopulation><ServicePopulation><PopulationId>4</PopulationId><PopulationName>Children of Substance Abusers*</PopulationName><IsOther>false</IsOther></ServicePopulation><ServicePopulation><PopulationId>5</PopulationId><PopulationName>Civic Groups/Coalitions</PopulationName><IsOther>false</IsOther></ServicePopulation></ArrayOfServicePopulation>'

SELECT  
    PopulationId = servicePopulations.value('(PopulationId)[1]', 'int'),
    PopulationName = servicePopulations.value('(PopulationName)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    IsOther = servicePopulations.value('(IsOther)[1]', 'varchar(10)')
FROM    
    @xml.nodes('/ArrayOfServicePopulation/ServicePopulation') results ( servicePopulations )
```

That should give you an output of:

```
PopulationId   PopulationName                   IsOther
-------------------------------------------------------
    1          Administrators                   false
    2          Adults                           false
    3          Business and Industry            false
    4          Children of Substance Abusers*   false
    5          Civic Groups/Coalitions          false
```

Comment: Sure as hell did. Thanks, marc